# eslint error the value of aria-current must be a single token from the following: page,step,location,date,time,true false

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, runtime-error

```
<div
     role="button"
     tabIndex="0"
     className="nav-link pad-0-r"
     aria-current={'${selectedTab === item ? 'page' : 'false'}'}
     onClick={()=> onClick(item)}
      onKeyDown={()=> onClick()}
     >
  {item}
</div>
```

**
for the security purpose i am not able to share the full code....
in this div with the help of map i am displaying the the navigation item names
but i amm getting this eslint error which i mentioned it. If anybody have any idea how to solve it plz suggest me.
**

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Looks like you are setting the `aria-current` to some amalgamation of string literals, not really sure what it resolves to in the DOM though.

```
aria-current={'${selectedTab === item ? 'page' : 'false'}'}
```

## Solution

Use string template correctly, note the backticks:

```
aria-current={`${selectedTab === item ? 'page' : 'false'}`}
```

Comment: backticks are not creating any issues. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the eslint error by removing the backticks completely:

`aria-current={selectedTab === item ? 'page' : 'false'}`